# Display error message separately

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am using `<h:outputText>` to display error or exception in top of the page.
Now I would like to display error message for particular text field using `<h:message>` tag.
However, the error is being displayed in both `<h:outputText>` and in `<h:message>` tag.
How can I display it only in the `<h:message>`?

Comment: I am using outputText attribute to display Error at top.

Comment: Be careful with the word 'asap'. A web forum is not a live chat, so good things take a while.

Comment: I want to display Error only at the Message Tag. The error is being displayed in both top and at the textField.

Comment: Can you provide some HTML source code?

Comment: Sorry i am not in a situation to revel my codes. please give me brief idea.

Comment: Please post the problem in SSCCE flavor. I can really not visualize with true code how this problem can ever be caused (and therefore I am not able to understand the problem and therefore I am not able to post an answer to solve the specific problem). Don't you perhaps you actually mean to say `<h:messages>` when you said `<h:outputText>`? Or is that `<h:outputText>` part of a homegrown `FacesMessage` display mechanism?

Comment: Are you not in control of the `<h:outputText/>`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your right, I think I had to face the same situaion in the past. I soleved this situation with using Javascript to clear the content of main error panel, if that contained a particular keyword.

I know it is a little bit dirty, as far as I know there no way to do it on server side. A hint: You can add a techniqcal keyword to your error message. Check the content of this keyword, then clear the main message panel and delete this string in the error message, by replacing this with an empty string.